# Error Installing SharePoint Server 2016 on Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter

Tags: 2016, prerequisites

I am having trouble installing SharePoint Server 2016 on a brand new instance of Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter. The Products Preparation Tool fails with this error: `The tool was unable to install Enable ASP.Net`
[image: The tool was unable to install Enable ASP.Net]

I have tried installing the prerequisites manually according to the details [here](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-2016-Prerequisit-17912ad2#content) and they seemed to install without error but the Products Preparation Tool continues to fail with the above error.

I think the relevant part of the log is as follows:

```
2018-03-29 08:51:14 - Enable ASP.Net
2018-03-29 08:51:14 - "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe" -i
2018-03-29 08:51:14 - Install process returned (0)
2018-03-29 08:51:14 - [In HRESULT format] (0)
2018-03-29 08:51:14 - "C:\Windows\system32\cscript.exe" "C:\Windows\system32\iisext.vbs" /enext "ASP.NET v4.0.30319"
2018-03-29 08:51:15 - Request for install time of Enable ASP.Net
2018-03-29 08:51:15 - Install process returned (0)
2018-03-29 08:51:15 - [In HRESULT format] (0)
2018-03-29 08:51:15 - "C:\Windows\system32\iisreset.exe" /noforce
2018-03-29 08:51:16 - Request for install time of Enable ASP.Net
2018-03-29 08:51:17 - Install process returned (0X425=1061)
2018-03-29 08:51:17 - [In HRESULT format] (0X80070425=-2147023835)
2018-03-29 08:51:17 - Last return code (0X425=1061)
2018-03-29 08:51:17 - Reading the following DWORD value/name...
2018-03-29 08:51:17 - Flags
2018-03-29 08:51:17 - from the following registry location...
2018-03-29 08:51:17 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Updates\UpdateExeVolatile
2018-03-29 08:51:17 - Reading the following string value/name...
2018-03-29 08:51:17 - PendingFileRenameOperations
2018-03-29 08:51:17 - from the following registry location...
2018-03-29 08:51:17 - SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager
2018-03-29 08:51:17 - Reading the following registry location...
2018-03-29 08:51:17 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update\RebootRequired
2018-03-29 08:51:17 - Error: The tool was unable to install Enable ASP.Net.
2018-03-29 08:51:17 - Last return code (0X425=1061)
2018-03-29 08:51:17 - Options for further diagnostics: 1. Look up the return code value 2. Download the prerequisite manually and verify size downloaded by the prerequisite installer. 3. Install the prerequisite manually from the given location without any command line options.
2018-03-29 08:51:17 - Cannot retry
2018-03-29 08:51:17 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
2018-03-29 08:51:17 - Windows Management Framework 3.0
2018-03-29 08:51:17 - Reading the following string value/name...
2018-03-29 08:51:17 - PowerShellVersion
2018-03-29 08:51:17 - from the following registry location...
2018-03-29 08:51:17 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\3\PowerShellEngine
2018-03-29 08:51:17 - The value is... 
2018-03-29 08:51:17 - 4.0
2018-03-29 08:51:17 - A higher version of the prerequisite above is already installed
```

I'm not sure if it's relevant but according to [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681383(v=vs.85).aspx) the return code 0X425=1061 means:

> ERROR_SERVICE_CANNOT_ACCEPT_CTRL 1061 (0x425) The service cannot
>   accept control messages at this time.

I have tried manually installing ASP.NET via `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis -enable -i` which returns this message:

> This option is not supported on this version of the operating system. 
>   Administrators should instead install/uninstall ASP.NET 4.5 with IIS8
>   using the "Turn Windows Features On/Off" dialog,  the Server Manager
>   management tool, or the dism.exe command line tool.

Checking the Add Roles and Features Wizard I can see that .NET 3.5 and .NET 4.5 are both installed:
[image: Add Roles and Features Wizard]

I have also ensured that Windows Update has installed any available updates on the server, uninstalled McAfee Antivirus, installed the April 2014 update for Server 2012 and copied c:\windows\system32\servermanager.exe to c:\windows\system32\servermanagercmd.exe

**Edit:** I have run the suggested command in PowerShell per the comment from @A.Saéed. I got the following output and the Products Preparation Tool installer failed again with the same error as at the top of the question.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Add-WindowsFeature NET-Framework-45-ASPNET, Web-Mgmt-Console, Web-Mgmt-Compat, Web-Metabase, Web-Lgcy-Mgmt-Console, Web-Lgcy-Scripting, Web-Mgmt-Tools, Web-Common-Http, Web-WMI, NET-HTTP-Activation,NET-Non-HTTP-Activ, NET-WCF-HTTP-Activation45

Success Restart Needed Exit Code      Feature Result
------- -------------- ---------      --------------
True    No             NoChangeNeeded {}
```

**Edit 2:** I have run `dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:IIS-ASPNET45` and gotten the following output:

> Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool Version: 6.3.9600.17031
>
> Image Version: 6.3.9600.17031
>
> Enabling feature(s)
>   [===========================99.8%========================= ] The
>   operation completed successfully.

The Products Preparation Tool installer still fails at the same point.

**Edit 3:** Per suggestions from [MHeld](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/33662/mheld):

- The World Wide Web Publishing Service is available, running and set
  to automatic startup. It does seem to get stopped by the pre
  requisites installer and when that fails the service does not get
  restarted automatically however.
- There don't seem to be any other related errors in Event Viewer.
- I created a local VM of Windows Server 2012 and the prerequisites installed without issue.
- Restarting the App_Pool didn't help
- This is the list of applied group policy objects from running `gpresult /r`:

  IT SVM
  corp.net Primary DNS Suffix
  IT HASS WS12 MbrSrv
  IT HASS WS12 Web v001
  IT-Infrastructure-Platform
  Default Domain Policy
  AM PrimaryDNS Suffix
  IT HASS WS12 MbrSrv
  WS08R2-WS12 Remote Desktop License Servers Settings
  Local Group Policy

How do I actually go about removing any of these? Running `gpedit` seems to show a lot of unrelated information.

**Edit 4:** Unfortunately I can't communicate directly with any domain administrators. This server is provided through a corporate cloud service. There is corporate IT support but they have already told me they don't support the cloud service and that they don't have any contact details for the corporate cloud service team.

Does anyone know why the Products Preparation Tool is failing with an error about something that is already installed or better yet how it can be resolved?

Comment: try enable the required features using windows powershell prior the SP installation using this:     Add-WindowsFeature NET-Framework-45-ASPNET, Web-Mgmt-Console, Web-Mgmt-Compat, Web-Metabase, Web-Lgcy-Mgmt-Console, Web-Lgcy-Scripting, Web-Mgmt-Tools, Web-Common-Http, Web-WMI, NET-HTTP-Activation, NET-Non-HTTP-Activ, NET-WCF-HTTP-Activation45

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @A.Saéed I have tried that but unfortunately it didn't help. I will edit the question with an update.

Comment: try manually register asp.net 4.5 with iis web server, what you did above is registering asp.net v4.0 , try this command : dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:IIS-ASPNET45

Comment: Thanks again @A.Saéed I have run that command and it has completed successfully but the installer still fails. I will update the question again.

Comment: Looks like you have a bunch of Group Policies applied to the systems. You are not able to "remove" those, as they are enforced by the ActiveDirectory Domain. Go to your Domain Administrators and ask them to exclude your servers.

Comment: As from edit 4 you Seem to be in a Bad Situation.. Is it possible to install a fresh machine with prerequisites and join it to the Domain afterwards? If this doesn‘t work you can Export all GPO Settings with ‚gpresult /h‘. Then Analyze every Setting and try to identify the „Bad“ one. Afterwards We can try to find an Individual way how to work around the GPO

Comment: I digged in my archive and was able to find the GroupPolicy which changed the AccessRights to a Service. This one broke a lot of stuff at a customer. I've updated my answer below with a screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

My ideas:

- Go to services.msc and check if `World Wide Web Publishing Service` is available and `Startup Type` is set to `Automatic`.
- Open an elevated CMD and type `gpresult /r`. Check for `Applied Group Policy Objects` both in `COMPUTER SETTINGS` and `USER SETTINGS`. If any GPOs apply, try to get rid of them. I have seen GPOs which change the [ACL of a Service](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/914392/best-practices-and-guidance-for-writers-of-service-discretionary-acces)

  - The following Group-Policy setting was responsible for the changed Service-ACLs. You might want to check your applied GPOs for this (`gpresult /h`) - especially for W3WP-Service
    [image: GPO that changes the ACL of a Service]
- Check Windows Eventviewer for related errors which are not logged to PreReq-InstallLog.
- [The service cannot accept control messages at this time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29761505/the-service-cannot-accept-control-messages-at-this-time)
- Do you have a "clean" installation of Windows Server 2012 R2 from ISO or Disc? Might be a modified image which breaks stuff.